# Performance of STL vector vs dynamic arrays

Tags: arrays, c++11, new-operator, stdvector, dynamic-arrays

I would like to know how big of a difference there is between the performance of c++ dynamic arrays and STL vectors. I know it could totally depend on your code and how you construct your vector, for example not taking advantage of std::vector::reserve and constructing vectors using std::vector::push_back could lead to poor performance. However, I cannot see why someone would choose dynamic arrays (with operator new[]) instead of using vectors with care. Is there a significant performance gap between correctly implemented STL vectors and dynamic arrays in general?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly they get used to use new[] and are not familiar with STL :)

Comment: If you don't use an ability of vector to grow automatically (which can be done with new[] only manually) but just reserve(...) space and use use it just as an array, in a Release configuration vector is almost the same as memory allocated with new[]. In a Debug mode it turns on index validation which  naturally has performance cost but helps in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

No, stl vectors are a thinnish wrapper over a dynamic array.

Basically new and delete are becoming obsolete in C++, with the exception of the code to implement the stl containers themselves. You should use an std::vector in preference to a hand-managed dynamic array.

Answer (score 1):

### There's no performance difference*

`std::vector` has been carefully specified to be implementable in terms of safely used dynamic arrays, exposing exactly the same features, and more.

[*] Except for expensive to move/copy/default construct types, where std::vector **wins** over `new Expensive[N]`, as it only allocates space with `vector::reserve`, the construction of `Expensive`s happens later.